# What is this device on all the Tour de France riders' bikes?

Tags: road-bike, racing, tour-de-france

What is the device behind the saddle on all the riders' bikes in the 2015 tour? I'm seeing it on almost every bike. It looks standardized and electronic.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a special device that gathers the following data, according to [this article](http://www.bikeradar.com/road/news/article/big-data-comes-to-the-tour-de-france-44682/):

> - the stage winner’s top speed, average speed and time per kilometer
> - the fastest riders up key climbs
> - the speed of the winner at the finish line
> - the top speed achieved by a rider on the day
> - average speed across all riders

Comment: Why isn't one of the big guys like Garmin already doing this, or rather, why didn't they beat Dimension Data to the punch?

Comment: Most likely because they are already sponsoring a team and there's only so much money in the marketing budget. Plus having title sponsorship of a team will deliver far more impressions than an unbranded foxtail device bolted to the back of a saddle.

Comment: Basically a GPS tracker.

Comment: doubles as a miniature mud guard

Answer (score 11):

They are GPS trackers with a wireless data connection, GSM or EDGE would be enough for the data rate, but it might be something faster. The company supplying them is [Dimension Data](http://www.dimensiondata.com/tourdefrance) you can sign up for a free data report at the end of each stage [here](http://www.dimensiondata.com/Global/Global-Events/Tour-de-France-Daily-Wrap/Pages/Registration.aspx).

Comment: GSM (i.e. 2G, 64 channels per antenna) is no longer supported in some advanced parts of the world (Germany IIRC), the frequencies are reused for faster mobile communication technologies.