# What is the total equipment weight of a tour rider?

Tags: weight, equipment

What is the total weight a Tdf rider carries up the hill apart from his own bodyweight? The bike is around 7kg, maybe a bottle with some water.. What about helmet, clothes, shoes etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weighing some of my own gear, and allowing some reduction because I'm not especially up to date ...

- Helmet 350g to 400g
- Shoes 300g to 350g
- Outfit 350g to 400g, 100 to 200g more on a cold or wet day.
- Misc 150g (sunnies, comms gear, etc)

Total... 1.15kg to 1.3kg, plus .1 or .2kg depending on conditions.

Comment: Two 500 ml bottles will add a further 1.1 kg.

Comment: Don't forget about those GPS devices behind the seatpost. I think they started in the 2015 tour. Not sure if they're used all the time but the size is not negligible. Probably a couple hundred grams.

Comment: @Carel 500ml bottles are UCI legal, but most in use are 600ml. They weigh about 80g empty, so the total would be 1360g. My reading of the question made bottles part of the bike.

Comment: @ebrohman As with bottles, I treated the GPS units as part of the bike. [Bike Radar](http://www.bikeradar.com/au/road/gear/article/tour-de-france-2015-road-bike-tech-44690/) says 20-30g. I would think about 50g. see also http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/31757/8273

Comment: @andy256: The UCI weighs the bikes with permanently attached equipment only. Bottles are not part of that.

Comment: @Carel That's true, but that is different to what the question asks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMsgzD-JFQs some bikes weigh up to 7.3kg

Comment: The riders will probably not go into a climb with two filled bottles, they will try to carry only as much water as necessary. On top of that, as the bottles gradually empty, and the empty ones get thrown to the side of the road, you can half the amount of weight of the water, as it is likely to be the average weight throughout the ascent. Yes they do swallow the water, but this is about bike weight. So I'll go with roughly 700g for water.